# Business Objects Web Intelligence automate report once for each parameter

Tags: excel, automation, reporting, business-objects

Using Business Objects Web Intelligence or Rich Client, is it possible to schedule a report to automatically run and export to Excel once for each parameter?

Background: I have a single report that needs to be saved to different Excel files once a month but I have a parameter on a "client" dimension which can contain 30+ values. Each value needs to generate its own Excel file. I would prefer to not run the report 30+ times each month.

Is there a way to schedule or change the WID query so that a separate file is generated for each parameter value? Or maybe an alternative idea for this manual process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a **Publication** with **Dynamic Recipients**.

You would need to create a second report that would produce a list of all values in your Client dimension.  This report would then serve as the source of the Dynamic Recipients in the Publication.  In the base report, you would remove the prompt on Client but make sure that Client is included in the report results.  Then in the Publication, you would set Personalization such that a filter is automatically applied to the Client dimension based on the values from the second report.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I think this is the right way to go. Unfortunately, I don't have the appropriate rights to complete the task, but I am trying to get to that point now and use this as a good starting point.